# How to derive this particular fraction with roots from another

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I came across a particular equation while using some trigonometric identities, for which I could not derive the other side. The left and right side are equal, but I was unable to derive the right side from the left side.

How do I get to the right side, when given the left side?

In other words: when left=right, should you always be able to rewrite one side to match the other side?

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$

---

If you wonder where these values came from (shouldnt matter for the answer), well both sides are equal to: $$\cos{15deg}$$

However, The left side was calculated using the **half-angle formula** (input the value for cosine of 30 degrees as 2x):
$$
\cos{30deg}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=2x
\\
\frac{1+\cos{2x}}{2}=\cos^2{x}
$$

The right side was calculated using the **angle subtraction formula**:
$$
\cos{45deg} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\\
\cos{30deg} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\\
\cos{45deg-30deg}=\cos{45}*\cos{30}+\sin{45}*\sin{30}
$$

The latter is somewhat simpler to solve and gives a nicer result without a root inside a root.

Comment: $$(\sqrt3+1)^2=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $$4+2\sqrt{3}$$ I dont see yet how this step helps me out